# How to create an email link using document.execCommand in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, hyperlink, execcommand

How to created a email link for the selected text using document.execCommand method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
document.execCommand("CreateLink", false, "mailto:someone@example.com");
```